# Why there is no String<T> in System.Collections.Generic of C#?

Tags: c#

C++ STL `string` is implemented by template.

I am learing C# at the moment, just curious what's the reason the .net designers didn't provide a generic string in System.Collections.Generic?

How can I have a int's string, double's string in C#?

Comment: However you may still consider creating your own `String<T>` if you need it.

Comment: For the same reason it doesn't exist in C++ either, the word "String" was already used for an important non-generic type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no such things as strings of `int`s or `double`s in C#<sup>*</sup>; the closest thing is a `List<T>`, but it does not support the typical string-specific operations, such as substrings, trimming, and so on.

You can do most of the things that you can with a string using .NET's LINQ. For example, `substring(1,5)` would be `list.Skip(1).Take(5).ToList()`.

---

<sup>*</sup> The same is true for C++: there is `basic_string` template that can be instantiated with other types, but `std::string` is an instance of a template class, not a template class itself.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a 'double's string' and 'int's string'. Its an 'array of doubles' and 'an array of ints'. That's why there's no generic 'string'.